# Entity Framework: field in table pointing to ID in same table (ParentID)

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, migration

I've got the following model of my Request table:

```
public class Request
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        public int Label_ID { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Memo { get; set; }

        public DateTime DeadLine { get; set; }

        **[ForeignKey("Label_ID, ID")]
        [InverseProperty("Request")]
        public int Parent_ID { get; set; }
        public virtual Request Parent { get; set; }**


        [ForeignKey("Label_ID")]
        public virtual Label Label { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RequestFrom")]
        public int RequestFrom_UserID { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser RequestFrom { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RequestTo")]
        public int RequestTo_UserID { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser RequestTo { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RequestAbout")]
        public int? RequestAbout_UserID { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser RequestAbout { get; set; }

        public int? Project_ID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Label_ID, Project_ID")]
        public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Parent_ID must be pointing to another Request by Label_ID and ID (composite key)

After creating a new add-migration I got the following error:

The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'Parent_ID' on type 'iMaSys.Models.Request' is not valid. The navigation property 'Label_ID, ID' was not found on the dependent type 'iMaSys.Models.Request'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.

I know how to successfully point to other tables as you can see in RequestAbout_UserID. That migration was successfull. Only after adding Parent_ID I can't seem to solve this error.

Any help?

Best regards, Janno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple `ForeignKeyAttribute`s to refer to one parent, but you should also use the `ColumnAttribute` to indicate the column order of the key parts. But you've got an auto reference here, so there's a slight problem. The standard way to do this by data annotations would be:

```
public class Request
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Label_ID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    [Column(Order = 1)] // to refer to ID
    public int Parent_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Request Parent { get; set; }
```

But this throws

> The configured column orders for the table 'Requests' contains duplicates. Ensure the specified column order values are distinct.

You can fix this by changing a column index:

```
public class Request
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Label_ID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)] // Changed
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Parent_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Request Parent { get; set; }
```

And EF accepts it. The absolute column indexes don't matter, the relative order is what counts.

Still... I wouldn't like the somewhat obscure feature that column 1 refers to column 2. The code doesn't explain itself. I would prefer fluent mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Request>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.Parent)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(p => new { p.Label_ID, p.Parent_ID })
```

Comment: I made one mistake, the parent should be nullable because not every request may have a parent. I changed to public int? Parent_ID {get;set;} and the migration was successfull.

However, if I enter a record in the table than I got the error:

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint FK_dbo.Request_dbo.Request_Label_ID_Parent_ID. Is this because it's a composite key?

Comment: I need to see what you do exactly. But the data structure demands that you always create a request that refers to its own `Label_ID` and `ID` to start a tree with a new `Label_ID`. It *may* be better to introduce a second FK column `Parent_Label_ID`. If you need more help, maybe it's better to start a new question so you can show all relevant code.

Comment: The parent is optional. But your suggestion is a good one, I'll create a FK column Parent_Label_ID. Thank you!